# setBackgroundMessageHandler not triggering when app is killed and another app is in foreground (iOS)

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, native

I'm encountering an issue with background notification handling in my React Native app using React Native Firebase on iOS.

*Problem Description:*

***Scenario***: When my app is killed and another app is in the foreground, setBackgroundMessageHandler doesn't execute for FCM notifications.

***Expected Behavior***: I expect setBackgroundMessageHandler to trigger even when the app is killed, enabling background tasks.

**Actual Behavior**: The handler only functions when no other app is in the foreground.

*Environment:*
React Native: 0.71.8
React Native Firebase Messaging: ~15.4.0
iOS Version: 16.3.1
Notifee: 7.7.1
Device Model: iPhone 10 (physical device)

*Configuration:*
FCM Setup: All good, please believe me.
Background Modes: "Remote notifications" enabled in Xcode.
Also have the headless setup following [rnfirebase doc](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#background-application-state).

```
// payload for fcm server
{
"to": "---this-is-correct-believe-me---",
  "content_available":true,
  "priority":"high",
  "apns": {
    "payload": {
      "aps": {
        "alert": {
          "title": "Test Push",
          "body": "Success! Push notification ! ",
          "sound": "default"
        }
      }
    },
    "headers": {
      "apns-push-type": "background",
      "apns-priority": "10",
      "apns-topic": "---this-is-also-correct-believe-me---"
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "title": "Test Push",
    "body": "Success! Push notification! ",
    "sound": "default"
  },
  "data": {
    "movieName": "",
  }
}
```

*Troubleshooting Attempts:*
Adjusted apns-priority: Tried setting it to 10, but no change.
Reviewed Payload: Verified notification and data fields are present.
Also, I'm using the `setBackgroundMessageHandler` and `onMessage` methods as mentioned in the [rnfirebase doc](https://rnfirebase.io/faqs-and-tips#on-ios-when-the-app-is-in-quit-state-the-setbackgroundmessagehandler-is-never-invoked-even-when-i-receive-the-notification-how-can-i-fix-this).

*Seeking guidance on:*
Potential causes for this behavior.
Troubleshooting steps to ensure reliable background handling in all scenarios.
Best practices for managing background tasks in React Native Firebase on iOS.

Comment: When your app is killed it will not receive background notifications until it is relaunched by the user.  Also, your payload doesn't meet the [requirement for a background notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app) - Your `app` dictionary should only contain a `content-available:1` entry.

Comment: Oh, I am not using the Apple's APNS directly, I am using the Firebase for my notification delivery, so I think Firebase should handle that part. If I am not mistaken.

Comment: No.  You have shown your payload in your question.  You clearly have an incorrect `aps` payload.  For background notifications this payload must only contain the `content-available` key.  Refer to the link in my previous comment.  Also the priority must be 5.